# uniform continuous proof take a look

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Hi take a look of my proof and fix if there is wrong or unnecessary part

> $F(x) = x^2 , \alpha \in [0,\infty] $ 
>   and prove $F(x)$ is not uniformly continuous

anyway

proof

assume that this$ f(x)$ is uniformly continuous.
then there should be a some limit point(??) exist $L$,
and $$y = L + \epsilon/2  , x = L-\epsilon/2$$
we can write this limit point as 
$$|x-y| < \epsilon$$

since $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous there should be exit of 
$$|f(x) - f(y)|  < \delta $$

If we proof there exist some $|f(x)- f(y)| > \delta $ this proof is done

$$|f(x) - f(y)|  < \delta   = |x^2 - y^2| < \delta = |x+y||x-y|$$

we know $|x-y| < \epsilon/2 $ then write   $x<y+\epsilon/2 $

$$|x+y| = |y+\epsilon/2 + y |,$$ then $$x = 2(y+\epsilon)$$

Therefore,  $$|x+y||x-Y|> \epsilon$$

there is contradiction.

Comment: To answer your formatting woes, $\in$ is written as \in, also people normally write \varepsilon to get $\varepsilon$ instead of \epsilon which gives the ugly $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having trouble understanding your argument - what are you getting at with the 'limit point'? You also seem to have the 'usual' role of $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ switched. Of course, this is just notational (and not mathematical), but sticking with conventions will make your work easier to read.

Basically, I'd say you have some idea what needs to be proved and how to prove it, but the biggest problem is **you make no indication of what conditions $x$ and $y$ must satisfy**. In particular, given an $\delta$ and $\epsilon$, there are going to be *some* points where $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$, you have to find a pair where this fails.

To show $f$ is not uniformly continuous, here's an outline.

1) If $f$ is uniformly continuous, then for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is $\delta > 0$ so that, for *any* $x,y$ such that $|x-y| < \delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$.

So to show it is **not** uniformly continuous, we need to show that for **some** $\epsilon > 0$, for **every** $\delta > 0$, there **exists** $x,y$ such that $|x-y| < \delta$, but $|f(x) - f(y)| > \epsilon$.

2) So, start with an $\epsilon$ that is convenient for you (since it has to hold for *any* $\epsilon$). Try $\epsilon = 1$ to begin with (we can always start over and make it smaller if this doesn't work).

3) Now, choose any $\delta > 0$. We want to find $x,y$ so that $|x-y| < \delta$, but $|x^2 - y^2| > 1$. Intuitively, we want to pick really big (but close together) $x$ and $y$ (close together so that $|x-y|$ is small, but the difference of their squares is big).

Let's set $y = x + \delta/2$ (so automatically, we have $|x-y| < \delta$) and then decide how big $x$ has to be. As you note, 
$$|x^2 - y^2| = |x + y||x-y| = |x + x + \delta/2||x - (x + \delta/2)| \\
= \frac{\delta}{2}\left|2x + \frac{\delta}{2}\right|\\
> \frac{\delta}{2}\left|2x\right| = \delta|x|$$

So, if we choose $x$ so that $|x| > \dfrac{1}{\delta}$, then we will have $|x^2 - y^2| > 1$ as needed.